# How to I use PIL Image.point(table) method to apply a threshold to a 256 gray image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, threshold

I have 8-bit greyscale TIFF images that I want to convert to Monochrome using a 75% white (decimal 190) threshold. In the Image.convert(mode) method section, the PIL manual says:

> "When translating a greyscale image into a bitlevel image (mode "1"), all non-zero values are set to 255 (white). To use other thresholds, use the point method."

The Image.point(table) method says that it maps each pixel through the given table.

> im.point(table, mode) => image
>   im.point(function, mode) => image
>
> > > "Map the image through table, and convert it on fly. In the current version of PIL , this can only be used to convert 'L' and 'P' images to '1' in one step, e.g. to threshold an image."

How do I create the table (or function) that corresponds to the 75% threshold I need?

Comment: pajton's answer is the one you want. You use 190, but I would use `p > 191` (I know, the difference is minor :).

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but a funny thing happened on the way to implementation. My images actually start as TIFF,CCITT group4. I thought it would be easy to convert to 8-bit grey. However, PIL reports "decoder group4 not available". Is there another imaging library that supports group4?

Answer (score 18):

I found the complete solution in this answer "[Write TIFF file in python from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262871/write-tiff-file-in-python-from-string)". The function must include "and 255"

```
threshold = 191  
im = im.point(lambda p: p > threshold and 255)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `im.point(lambda p: p > 190)` and post the results.

Comment: As tahoar says above, you do seem to need the and 255